# Is there a function that grows slower than the factorial function and whose derivative grows faster than the function itself?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, factorial

Is there a function that grows slower than the factorial function and whose derivative grows faster than the function itself? In symbols,
is there a function $f(x)$ that satisfies $f(x) = o(x!)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/f'(x) = 0$?

Comment: $f(x)=2^{x\ln(x)}$ for instance.

Comment: Hi Algo! Please use Mathjax :)

Comment: Hi, @Stockfish: the MathJax hint is even better if you include a link like this one: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Stirling's formula says $x! = e^{x \ln(x) - x + O(\ln(x))}$, so we can do $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$, where $g(x)$ is any function that grows more slowly than $x \ln(x)$, but faster than $ax$ for any constant $a$. One obvious one to use could be $g(x) = x \ln \ln x$, which makes $$f(x) = e^{x \ln \ln x},$$ for which $$f'(x) = e^{x \ln \ln x} \left( \ln \ln x + \frac{1}{\ln x} \right) = f(x)\ln \ln x + \frac{f(x)}{\ln x}$$ clearly satisfies $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \infty$.

It's easy to verify that for this choice of $f(x)$, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x!} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{x \ln \ln x - x \ln x + x + O(\ln x)} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

For any $r>0$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{r^x}{x!}=0
$$We can augment the exponent a little bit: for instance,
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{r^{x+\log(x)^2}}{x!}=0
$$But not too much: if $r>1$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{r^{x^{1+\varepsilon}}}{x!}=\infty
$$

Comment: I was motivated by Stirling's Formula: for large $n$,
$$
n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n
$$